# get all records that was equal to the give id laravel eloqouent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to retrieved the records that has an 'user_id' of '1', below is what ive tried so far but unfortunately not working, any ideas, help?

```
$if_married = if_married::where('user_id', '=', '1');

return response()->json(['success' => true, 'if_married' => $if_married ]);
```

but returns me an empty json array.

my database set up (refer below)

```
id (primary, auto_increment, int), children (varchar 250), type_of_delivery (varchar 250), dates (varchar 250), user_id (int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do some changes

```
$if_married = if_married::where('user_id', '=', '1')->get();
```

Comment: @Code Demon If this answer is ok,make it accepted,that another user can understand.